# Preventing registered users from sharing passwords

Tags: security

Below is a proposal for dealing with a situation of website security. I am wondering whether it seems feasible, from both a technical and usability point of view. I want to make sure that the proposal does contain any glaring errors.

A. THE WEBSITE

The website in question is a school website where students may purchase various items. These students get an account on the website with a username and password, which they can use to login. Once they login, they have access to protected pages with private content which are unavailable to the public at large.

B. THE SECURITY CONCERN

The owners of the website wish to prevent a situation where a single student signs up on the website, obtains a username and password, and then circulates those credentials to a circle of friends who are then able to login to the website and illegally view the private content.

C. THE SOLUTION

The central idea we have come up with to deal with this security problem is to permit each student to login to the website on two devices only. Once a student logs in on two different devices, they are restricted to those two devices. If they then attempt to login on a third device, the system would simply not permit them to do so. It is our understanding that other websites offering private content, such as Netflix, use such an approach.

D. IMPLEMENTATION

Two ideas come to mind to implement the above security measure: a. IP address. b. Cookies. We rule out IP addresses, which can change, and choose cookies. Websites such as amazon.com allow their customers to login once, and then whenever they return to the website, they are always recognized. This is almost certainly achieved through cookies.

Thus each time a student logs in, we will store on their device a cookie. And we will also store this cookie in our database under that student's account. Thus each time a student logs in on any device, we will check whether the device they are currently logging in on contains the cookie we have stored for that student. If it does not, we will know that the student is logging in on a different device. We will thus be able to know how many devices the student is trying to login on.

E. DRAWBACKS

We have identified at least three possible drawbacks to this approach:

1. Clearing Cookies. People can, for a variety of reasons, choose to clear the cookies from their computer.
2. A bona fide person may occasionally not have access to their usual device, and wish to login on a different computer.
3. People do purchase new devices from time to time.

These are examples of situations where a bona fide user, for legitimate reasons, wishes to login, but will be unable to, due to the website's security restriction of two devices.

We have some ideas as to how to build logic into the system to deal with such situations, which we may implement in the future, but for the time being, we feel that such situations are sufficiently rare that we do not need to handle them programmatically.

Rather, for now, in the event that a student is locked out, they will get a screen with a message explaining why we have not allowed them into the system, and a button which they can click on which will automatically generate an email to the site administrators.

The email will inform them that a student wishes to login on a third device. The administators can then contact the student, and, if they are satisfied that the need is bona fide, they will be able to take steps from the CMS to allow that student in.

The size of the student body is sufficiently manageable that the above approach should be feasible.

F. FAIR WARNING

We will inform the students of these security measures when their account is activated, in order to prevent unpleasant surprises.

Comment: You might get better feedback at https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Glaring fail 1: "circulates those credentials to a circle of friends who are then able to login to the website and illegally view the private content." If the content has any value, it will likely be copied.

Comment: Glaring fail 2: "cookie" I dump cookies regularly, and so do many other security-conscious people. This would tick me off. Probably not a good idea to tick off the people you don't want copying your content. Also, people have figured out that they can share cookies! Using this method, they usually don't even have to worry someone will change the password on them.

Comment: In short, DRM is a time/money pit that simply does not work. Don't throw your time/money in it.

Comment: I'm curious why I got two downvotes for my question. Can someone please explain why.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical example of trying to fix via IT a real-world policy problem; in this case, forbidding students to share their credentials.

The solution you are proposing limits usability (for the reasons which you already listed under Drawbacks) and does not ensure security because cookies - and especially content - can be copied around.  In short, it is feasible, but can easily be circumvented.  It's up to you to decide whether it is worth to implement it.  It would probably be better to enforce the "no sharing credentials" rule e.g. set up random checks and send any student caught violating the rule to the Dean.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. What precisely do you mean by "set up random checks"?

Comment: Check whether the student is logged in with his/her ID.  This can easily be enforced on school's computers; on the student's private devices, that's another matter.